# Window function not able to capture all rows, skipping the row with value 'null'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My window function is not capturing the first row with "Rate" = null. As there is only one country code there should be single window right?
The expected output should be 20.519 for column "New" in all rows.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
W = Window.partitionBy(DF.Country).orderBy(DF.Date.desc())
DF.select("*",first("Exchange_Rate",ignorenulls=True).over(W))
```

[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the frame of the windows is assumed implicitly by Spark as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` (see [Spark Gotchas](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/05_spark_sql_and_dataset_api.md#rows-between-and-range-between-clauses)) hence, for `Date` `202201` `New` is null. Since no row before it has a non-null `Rate`. Explicitly defining the frame will resolve the issue.

```py
data = [("202201", "MXN", None,),
        ("202112", "MXN", 20.519,),
        ("202111", "MXN", 21.364,),
        ("202111", "MXN", 21.364,), ]

DF = spark.createDataFrame(data, "Date:string,Country:string,Rate:Double")

from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
W = Window.partitionBy(DF.Country).orderBy(DF.Date.desc()).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
DF.select("*",(first("Rate",ignorenulls=True).over(W)).alias("New")).show()

"""
+------+-------+------+------+
|  Date|Country|  Rate|   New|
+------+-------+------+------+
|202201|    MXN|  null|20.519|
|202112|    MXN|20.519|20.519|
|202111|    MXN|21.364|20.519|
|202111|    MXN|21.364|20.519|
+------+-------+------+------+
"""
```